# Can system:index be changed in an ImageCollection using map?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to simplify the system:index property of an `ImageCollection` containing Landsat 5, 7, and 8, images. Because collections are merged, they get `1_`, prefixes in `system:index`. I'm sure that `system:index` is unique, so I'm trying to remove the prefixes using the following code:

```
Collection = Collection.map(function(image){return image.set("system:index",image.getString('system:index').replace('(\\d_){1,2}L','L'))})
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. I understand that `system:index`, must be unique, and it is. Regardless, I would expect an error, if it's not unique, and not, not being allowed to modify it.

If I try to set a different property, in the same way, it works as expected, so the problem seems to be setting `"system:index"`. Is it completely forbidden to modify `"system:index"`? Why doesn't it yield an error then? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about `system:index` being read-only.

```
// Works as expected, i.e. the SATELLITE property is changed correctly
Collection = Collection.map(function(image){return image.set("SATELLITE",image.getString('system:index').replace('(\\d_){1,2}L','L'))})
```

[Link with testing code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3c5ca76c5e1feccf44f0295c7516d86)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change system:index with a mapped function, but you can set system:id which might meet your needs. It's used in preference to system:index in some situations (like when printing in the console).

If that doesn't do what you want, then you'll need to convert the collection to a list, map over that to set system:index (which doesn't have any special meaning in the context of a list), and then convert back to an ImageCollection.

Comment: Setting a separate property wouldn't have worked, because ```.toBands()``` relies on ```system:index```. The final solution was to just rename bands after ```.toBands()```. My questions are not that much intended to find a solution, as they are to better understand how EE works, and to give feedback to EE developers about how users understand and use EE, since I know you read these questions. It would be nice if changing ```system:index``` in a ```.map()``` would give an error. I don't know exactly where would be best to suggest this.